# Qt выдаёт разные ошибки при запуске и при закрытии

Tags: c++, qt

Установил на новый ноутбук Qt. Он у меня выдаёт ошибки при запуске и при закрытии. Причём в разной последовательности и количестве. Ошибки ниже на картинках.

Перепробовал разные методы. И удалял, и в QtCreator.ini лазил, и в исключения антивируса добавил (Avast), и от администратора запускал - ничего не помогло((

Нутром чую, что разгадка где-то рядом и дело вовсе не в бабине, но найти решение не получается...

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Я не очень дружу с windows, но разве в appdata можно удалять файлы без прав администратора?

Comment: Да, только при следующем запуске Qt их восстанавливает.

Comment: Похоже на баг: https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTCREATORBUG-7668 , хотя у меня никогда не проявлялось...

Comment: Вчера читал об этом. В принципе на работу Qt эти ошибки не влияют. Но дико бесит, когда при запуске/выходе они выскакивают.
P.S: Или я ещё не обнаружил на, что они влияют...

Comment: Не стоит ли атрибут только чтение на какую-то из папок по пути к файлам настроек?

Comment: На сами папки стоит и не убирается. А на файлы о которых вещают ошибки - не стоит.